# Computing pairwise Hamming distance between all rows of two integer matrices/data frames

Tags: r, apply, sapply, tapply, hamming-distance

I have two data frames, `df1` with reference data and `df2` with new data. For each row in `df2`, I need to find the best (and the second best) matching row to `df1` in terms of hamming distance.

I used `e1071` package to compute hamming distance. Hamming distance between two vectors `x` and `y` can be computed as for example:

```
x <- c(356739, 324074, 904133, 1025460, 433677, 110525, 576942, 526518, 299386,
       92497, 977385, 27563, 429551, 307757, 267970, 181157, 3796, 679012, 711274,
       24197, 610187, 402471, 157122, 866381, 582868, 878)

y <- c(356739, 324042, 904133, 959893, 433677, 110269, 576942, 2230, 267130,
       92496, 960747, 28587, 429551, 438825, 267970, 181157, 36564, 677220,
       711274, 24485, 610187, 404519, 157122, 866413, 718036, 876)

xm <- sapply(x, intToBits)
ym <- sapply(y, intToBits)

distance <- sum(sapply(1:ncol(xm), function(i) hamming.distance(xm[,i], ym[,i])))
```

and the resulting distance is 25. Yet I need to do this for all rows of `df1` and `df2`. A trivial method takes a double loop nest and looks terribly slow.

Any ideas how to do this more efficiently? In the end I need to append to `df2`:

- a column with the row id from `df1` that gives the lowest distance;
- a column with the lowest distance;
- a column with the row id from `df1` that gives the 2nd lowest distance;
- a column with the second lowest distance.

Thanks.

Comment: should be able to do it with `apply` and `match`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Fast computation of hamming distance between two integers vectors of equal length**

As I said in my comment, we can do:

```
hmd0 <- function(x,y) sum(as.logical(xor(intToBits(x),intToBits(y))))
```

to compute hamming distance between **two integers vectors of equal length** `x` and `y`. This only uses R base, yet is more efficient than `e1071::hamming.distance`, **because it is vectorized!**

For the example `x` and `y` in your post, this gives 25. (*My other answer will show what we should do, if we want pairwise hamming distance.*)

---

**Fast hamming distance between a matrix and a vector**

If we want to compute the hamming distance between a single `y` and multiple `x`s, i.e., the hamming distance between a vector and a matrix, we can use the following function.

```
hmd <- function(x,y) {
  rawx <- intToBits(x)
  rawy <- intToBits(y)
  nx <- length(rawx)
  ny <- length(rawy)
  if (nx == ny) {
    ## quick return
    return (sum(as.logical(xor(rawx,rawy))))
    } else if (nx < ny) {
    ## pivoting
    tmp <- rawx; rawx <- rawy; rawy <- tmp
    tmp <- nx; nx <- ny; ny <- tmp
    }
  if (nx %% ny) stop("unconformable length!") else {
    nc <- nx / ny  ## number of cycles
    return(unname(tapply(as.logical(xor(rawx,rawy)), rep(1:nc, each=ny), sum)))
    }
  }
```

Note that:

1. `hmd` performs computation **column-wise**. It is designed to be **CPU cache friendly**. In this way, if we want to do some row-wise computation, we should transpose the matrix first;
2. there is no obvious loop here; instead, we use `tapply()`.

---

**Fast hamming distance computation between two matrices/data frames**

This is what you want. The following function `foo` takes two data frames or matrices `df1` and `df2`, computing the distance between `df1` and each row of `df2`. argument `p` is an integer, showing how many results you want to retain. `p = 3` will keep the smallest 3 distances with their row ids in `df1`.

```
foo <- function(df1, df2, p) {
  ## check p
  if (p > nrow(df2)) p <- nrow(df2)
  ## transpose for CPU cache friendly code
  xt <- t(as.matrix(df1))
  yt <- t(as.matrix(df2))
  ## after transpose, we compute hamming distance column by column
  ## a for loop is decent; no performance gain from apply family
  n <- ncol(yt)
  id <- integer(n * p)
  d <- numeric(n * p)
  k <- 1:p
  for (i in 1:n) {
    distance <- hmd(xt, yt[,i])
    minp <- order(distance)[1:p]
    id[k] <- minp
    d[k] <- distance[minp]
    k <- k + p
    }
  ## recode "id" and "d" into data frame and return
  id <- as.data.frame(matrix(id, ncol = p, byrow = TRUE))
  colnames(id) <- paste0("min.", 1:p)
  d <- as.data.frame(matrix(d, ncol = p, byrow = TRUE))
  colnames(d) <- paste0("mindist.", 1:p)
  list(id = id, d = d)
  }
```

Note that:

1. transposition is done at the beginning, according to reasons before;
2. a `for` loop is used here. But this is actually efficient because there is considerable computation done in each iteration. It is also more elegant than using `*apply` family, since we ask for multiple output (row id `id` and distance `d`).

---

**Experiment**

This part uses small dataset to test/demonstrate our functions.

Some toy data:

```
set.seed(0)
df1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:10), ncol = 2))  ## 5 rows 2 cols
df2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:6), ncol = 2))  ## 3 rows 2 cols
```

Test `hmd` first (needs transposition):

```
hmd(t(as.matrix(df1)), df2[1, ])  ## df1 & first row of df2
# [1] 2 4 6 2 4
```

Test `foo`:

```
foo(df1, df2, p = 2)

# $id
#   min1 min2
# 1    1    4
# 2    2    3
# 3    5    2

# $d
#   mindist.1 mindist.2
# 1         2         2
# 2         1         3
# 3         1         3
```

If you want to append some columns to `df2`, you know what to do, right?

Comment: Thank you very much. Very clear what you did. One issue I detected with the foo function is that you hard coded the ncol to 3 towards the end of the code. I think you meant to set this to p.

Comment: Sure will. Thanks again. I'm also trying to figure out how to integrate two more numbers: the number of bits set to one in both df2 and lowest distance df1. Do I need a new function to do this or can this be integrated in the hmd function? Any pointers how I can do this?

Comment: Thanks. I have created a new post titled "Computing number of bits that are set to 1 for matching rows in terms of hamming distance between two data frames"

Answer (score 3):

Please don't be surprised why I take another section. This part gives something relevant. **It is not what OP asks for, but may help any readers.**

---

**General hamming distance computation**

In the previous answer, I start from a function `hmd0` that computes hamming distance between two integer vectors of the same length. This means if we have 2 integer vectors:

```
set.seed(0)
x <- sample(1:100, 6)
y <- sample(1:100, 6)
```

we will end up with a scalar:

```
hmd0(x,y)
# 13
```

What if we want to compute **pairwise hamming distance of two vectors**?

In fact, a simple modification to our function `hmd` will do:

```
hamming.distance <- function(x, y, pairwise = TRUE) {
  nx <- length(x)
  ny <- length(y)
  rawx <- intToBits(x)
  rawy <- intToBits(y)
  if (nx == 1 && ny == 1) return(sum(as.logical(xor(intToBits(x),intToBits(y)))))
  if (nx < ny) {
    ## pivoting
    tmp <- rawx; rawx <- rawy; rawy <- tmp
    tmp <- nx; nx <- ny; ny <- tmp
    }
  if (nx %% ny) stop("unconformable length!") else {
    bits <- length(intToBits(0)) ## 32-bit or 64 bit?
    result <- unname(tapply(as.logical(xor(rawx,rawy)), rep(1:ny, each = bits), sum))
    }
  if (pairwise) result else sum(result)
  }
```

Now

```
hamming.distance(x, y, pairwise = TRUE)
# [1] 0 3 3 2 5 0
hamming.distance(x, y, pairwise = FALSE)
# [1] 13
```

---

**Hamming distance matrix**

If we want to compute the hamming distance matrix, for example,

```
set.seed(1)
x <- sample(1:100, 5)
y <- sample(1:100, 7)
```

The distance matrix between `x` and `y` is:

```
outer(x, y, hamming.distance)  ## pairwise argument has no effect here

#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
# [1,]    2    3    4    3    4    4    2
# [2,]    7    6    3    4    3    3    3
# [3,]    4    5    4    3    6    4    2
# [4,]    2    3    2    5    6    4    2
# [5,]    4    3    4    3    2    0    2
```

We can also do:

```
outer(x, x, hamming.distance)

#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    0    5    2    2    4
# [2,]    5    0    3    5    3
# [3,]    2    3    0    2    4
# [4,]    2    5    2    0    4
# [5,]    4    3    4    4    0
```

In the latter situation, we end up with a symmetric matrix with 0 on the diagonal. Using `outer` is inefficient here, but it is still more efficient than writing R loops. Since our `hamming.distance` is written in R code, I would stay with using `outer`. In [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37032988/4891738) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37030260/4891738), I demonstrate the idea of using compiled code. This of course requires writing a C version of `hamming.distance`, but I will not show it here.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative solution that uses only base R, and should be very fast, especially when your df1 and df2 have many rows. The main reason for this is that it does not use *any* R-level looping for calculating the Hamming distances, such as for-loops, while-loops, or *apply functions. Instead, it uses [matrix multiplication for computing the Hamming distance](https://johanndejong.wordpress.com/2015/10/02/faster-hamming-distance-in-r-2/). In R, this is much faster than any approach using R-level looping. Also note that using an *apply function will not necessarily make your code any faster than using a for loop. Two other efficiency-related features of this approach are: (1) It uses [partial sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_sorting) for finding the best two matches for each row in df2, and (2) It stores the entire bitwise representation of df1 in one matrix (same for df2), and does so in one single step, without using any R-level loops.

The function that does all the work:

```
# INPUT:       
# X corresponds to your entire df1, but is a matrix
# Y corresponds to your entire df2, but is a matrix
# OUTPUT:
# Matrix with four columns corresponding to the values 
# that you specified in your question
fun <- function(X, Y) {

  # Convert integers to bits 
  X <- intToBits(t(X))
  # Reshape into matrix
  dim(X) <- c(ncols * 32, nrows)

  # Convert integers to bits
  Y <- intToBits(t(Y))
  # Reshape into matrix
  dim(Y) <- c(ncols * 32, nrows)

  # Calculate pairwise hamming distances using matrix 
  # multiplication. 
  # Columns of H index into Y; rows index into X.
  # The code for the hamming() function was retrieved
  # from this page:
  # https://johanndejong.wordpress.com/2015/10/02/faster-hamming-distance-in-r-2/
  H <- hamming(X, Y)

  # Now, for each row in Y, find the two best matches 
  # in X. In other words: for each column in H, find 
  # the two smallest values and their row indices.
  t(apply(H, 2, function(h) {
    mindists <- sort(h, partial = 1:2)
    c(
      ind1 = which(h == mindists[1])[1],
      val1 = mindists[1],
      hmd2 = which(h == mindists[2])[1],
      val2 = mindists[2]
    )
  }))
}
```

To call the function on some random data:

```
# Generate some random test data with no. of columns 
# corresponding to your data
nrows <- 1000
ncols <- 26 

# X corresponds to your df1
X <- matrix(
  sample(1e6, nrows * ncols, replace = TRUE), 
  nrow = nrows, 
  ncol = ncols
)

# Y corresponds to your df2
Y <- matrix(
  sample(1e6, nrows * ncols, replace = TRUE), 
  nrow = nrows, 
  ncol = ncols
)

res <- fun(X, Y)
```

The above example with 1000 rows in both X (df1) and Y (df2) took about 1.1 - 1.2 seconds to run on my laptop.