# Computing number of bits that are set to 1 for matching rows in terms of hamming distance between two data frames

Tags: r, apply, sapply, tapply, hamming-distance

I have two data frames of same number of columns (but not rows) `df1` and `df2`. For each row in `df2`, I was able to find the best (and second best) matching rows from `df1` in terms of hamming distance, in [my previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37913440/4891738). In that post, we have been using the following example data:

```
set.seed(0)
df1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:10), ncol = 2))  ## 5 rows 2 cols
df2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:6), ncol = 2))  ## 3 rows 2 cols
```

I now need to compute the number of bits equal to 1 for:

1. each row in `df2`
2. the best matching rows in `df1`
3. the second matching rows in `df1`

The number of bits equal to 1 of an integer `a` maybe computed as

```
sum(as.integer(intToBits(a)))
```

And I have applied this to @ZheyuanLi's original function, so I have got item 1>. However I'm unable to apply the same logic to get item 2> and 3>, by simple modification of @ZheyuanLi's function.

Below are the functions from @ZheyuanLi's with modification:

```
hmd <- function(x,y) {
    rawx <- intToBits(x)
    rawy <- intToBits(y)
    nx <- length(rawx)
    ny <- length(rawy)
    if (nx == ny) {
        ## quick return
        return (sum(as.logical(xor(rawx,rawy))))
    } else if (nx < ny) {
        ## pivoting
        tmp <- rawx; rawx <- rawy; rawy <- tmp
        tmp <- nx; nx <- ny; ny <- tmp
    }
    if (nx %% ny) stop("unconformable length!") else {
        nc <- nx / ny  ## number of cycles
        return(unname(tapply(as.logical(xor(rawx,rawy)), rep(1:nc, each=ny), sum)))
    }
}

foo <- function(df1, df2, p = 2) {
    ## check p
    if (p > nrow(df2)) p <- nrow(df2)
    ## transpose for CPU cache friendly code
    xt <- t(as.matrix(df1))
    yt <- t(as.matrix(df2))
    ## after transpose, we compute hamming distance column by column
    ## a for loop is decent; no performance gain from apply family
    n <- ncol(yt)
    id <- integer(n * p)
    d <- numeric(n * p)
    sb <- integer(n)
    k <- 1:p
    for (i in 1:n) {
        set.bits <- sum(as.integer(intToBits(yt[,i])))
        distance <- hmd(xt, yt[,i])
        minp <- order(distance)[1:p]
        id[k] <- minp
        d[k] <- distance[minp]
        sb[i] <- set.bits
        k <- k + p
    }
    ## recode "id", "d" and "sb" into data frame and return
    id <- as.data.frame(matrix(id, ncol = p, byrow = TRUE))
    colnames(id) <- paste0("min.", 1:p)
    d <- as.data.frame(matrix(d, ncol = p, byrow = TRUE))
    colnames(d) <- paste0("mindist.", 1:p)
    sb <- as.data.frame(matrix(sb, ncol = 1))  ## no need for byrow as you have only 1 column
    colnames(sb) <- "set.bits.1"
    list(id = id, d = d, sb = sb)
}
```

Running these gives:

```
> foo(df1, df2)
$id
  min1 min2  ## row id for best/second best match in df1
1    1    4
2    2    3
3    5    2

$d
  mindist.1 mindist.2  ## minimum 2 hamming distance
1         2         2
2         1         3
3         1         3

$sb
  set.bits.1  ## number of bits equal to 1 for each row of df2
1          3
2          2
3          4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, after reading through while re-editing your question (many times!), I think I know what you want. Essentially we need change nothing to `hmd()`. Your required items 1>, 2>, 3> can all be computed after the `for` loop in `foo()`.

To get item 1>, which you called `sb`, we can use a `tapply()`. However, your computation of `sb` along the `for` loop is fine, so I will not change it. In the following, I will demonstrate the basic procedure to get item 2> and item 3>.

The `id` vector inside `foo()` stores all matching rows in `df1`:

```
id <- c(1, 4, 2, 3, 5, 2)
```

so we can simply extract those rows of `df1` (actually, columns of `xt`), to compute the number of bits equal to 1. As you can see, there are lots of duplicity in `id`, so we can only computes on `unique(id)`:

```
id0 <- sort(unique(id))
## [1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

We now extract those subset columns of `xt`:

```
sub_xt <- xt[, id0]
##    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
## V1    9    3   10    5    6
## V2    2    4    8    7    1
```

To compute the number of bits equal to 1 for each column of `sub_xt`, we again use `tapply()` and vectorized approach.

```
rawbits <- as.integer(intToBits(as.numeric(sub_xt)))  ## convert sub_xt to binary
sbxt0 <- unname(tapply(X = rawbits,
                      INDEX =  rep(1:length(id0), each = length(rawbits) / length(id0)),
                      FUN = sum))
## [1] 3 3 3 5 3
```

Now we need to map `sbxt0` to `sbxt`:

```
sbxt <- sbxt0[match(id, id0)]
## [1] 3 5 3 3 3 3
```

Then we can convert `sbxt` to a data frame `sb1`:

```
sb1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sbxt, ncol = p, byrow = TRUE))
colnames(sb1) <- paste(paste0("min.", 1:p), "set.bits.1", sep = ".")
##   min.1.set.bits.1 min.2.set.bits.1
## 1                3                5
## 2                3                3
## 3                3                3
```

Finally we can assemble these things up:

```
foo <- function(df1, df2, p = 2) {
    ## check p
    if (p > nrow(df2)) p <- nrow(df2)
    ## transpose for CPU cache friendly code
    xt <- t(as.matrix(df1))
    yt <- t(as.matrix(df2))
    ## after transpose, we compute hamming distance column by column
    ## a for loop is decent; no performance gain from apply family
    n <- ncol(yt)
    id <- integer(n * p)
    d <- numeric(n * p)
    sb2 <- integer(n)
    k <- 1:p
    for (i in 1:n) {
        set.bits <- sum(as.integer(intToBits(yt[,i])))
        distance <- hmd(xt, yt[,i])
        minp <- order(distance)[1:p]
        id[k] <- minp
        d[k] <- distance[minp]
        sb2[i] <- set.bits
        k <- k + p
    }
    ## compute "sb1"
    id0 <- sort(unique(id))
    sub_xt <- xt[, id0]
    rawbits <- as.integer(intToBits(as.numeric(sub_xt)))  ## convert sub_xt to binary
    sbxt0 <- unname(tapply(X = rawbits,
                           INDEX =  rep(1:length(id0), each = length(rawbits) / length(id0)),
                           FUN = sum))
    sbxt <- sbxt0[match(id, id0)]
    sb1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sbxt, ncol = p, byrow = TRUE))
    colnames(sb1) <- paste(paste0("min.", 1:p), "set.bits.1", sep = ".")
    ## recode "id", "d" and "sb2" into data frame and return
    id <- as.data.frame(matrix(id, ncol = p, byrow = TRUE))
    colnames(id) <- paste0("min.", 1:p)
    d <- as.data.frame(matrix(d, ncol = p, byrow = TRUE))
    colnames(d) <- paste0("mindist.", 1:p)
    sb2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sb2, ncol = 1))  ## no need for byrow as you have only 1 column
    colnames(sb2) <- "set.bits.1"
    list(id = id, d = d, sb1 = sb1, sb2 = sb2)
}
```

Now, running `foo(df1, df2)` gives:

```
> foo(df1,df2)
$id
   min.1 min.2
 1     1     4
 2     2     3
 3     5     2

 $d
  mindist.1 mindist.2
1         2         2
2         1         3
3         1         3

$sb1
   min.1.set.bits.1 min.2.set.bits.1
 1                3                5
 2                3                3
 3                3                3

$sb2
  set.bits.1
1          3
2          2
3          4
```

Note that I have renamed the `sb` you used to `sb2`.

Comment: Works perfect. Exactly what I needed. Thanks