# Temporal distance matrix from dates

Tags: r, date, datetime

From a very simple dataframe like

```
    time1 <- as.Date("2010/10/10")
    time2 <- as.Date("2010/10/11")
    time3 <- as.Date("2010/10/12")
    test <- data.frame(Sample=c("A","B", "C"), Date=c(time1, time2, time3))
```

how can i obtain a matrix with pairwise temporal distances (elapsed time in days between samples) between the Samples A, B, C?

```
   A  B  C
A  0  1  2
B  1  0  1
C  2  1  0
```

/edit: changed the format of the dates. sorry for inconveniences

Comment: @ZheyuanLi Write an answer, then you can also properly format your code.

Comment: In general the solution to this kind of problem in R is the `dist` function. In your case, `dist(test$Date)` “works” more or less; however, `dist` doesn’t know about time and so the result are just numbers, not `timediff` objects, which may be a problem. For that reason, the comment above by Zheyuan shows a better answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get actual days calculations, you can convert the days to a date since some pre-defined date and then use `dist`. Example below (converted your days, I doubt they were represented how you expected them to be):

```
time1 <- as.Date("02/10/10","%m/%d/%y")
time2 <- as.Date("02/10/11","%m/%d/%y")
time3 <- as.Date("02/10/12","%m/%d/%y")
test <- data.frame(Sample=c("A","B", "C"), Date=c(time1, time2, time3))
days_s2010 <- difftime(test$Date,as.Date("01/01/10","%m/%d/%y"))
dist_days <- as.matrix(dist(days_s2010,diag=TRUE,upper=TRUE))
rownames(dist_days) <- test$Sample; colnames(dist_days) <- test$Sample
```

`dist_days` then prints out:

```
> dist_days
    A   B   C
A   0 365 730
B 365   0 365
C 730 365   0
```

---

Actually `dist` doesn't need to convert the dates to days since some time, simply doing `dist(test$Date)` will work for days.

Comment: The OP edited the dates when I was writing this answer. In the updated dates simply doing `dist(test$Date)` gives the answer. The way the dates were formatted previously I thought they should be different years though.

Comment: I didnt know dist() was good for this formal as well! Thank you so far.

Answer (score 6):

**Using outer()**

You don't need to work with a data frame. In your example, we can collect your dates in a single vector and use `outer()`

```
x <- c(time1, time2, time3)
abs(outer(x, x, "-"))

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    1    2
[2,]    1    0    1
[3,]    2    1    0
```

Note I have added an `abs()` outside, so that you will only get positive time difference, i.e, the time difference "today - yesterday" and "yesterday - today" are both 1.

If your data are pre-stored in a data frame, you can extract that column as a vector and then proceed.

**Using `dist()`**

As Konrad mentioned, `dist()` is often used for computation of distance matrix. The greatest advantage is that it will only compute lower/upper triangular matrix (diagonal are 0), while copying the rest. On the other hand, `outer()` forces computing all matrix elements, not knowing the symmetry.

However, `dist()` takes numerical vectors, and only computes some classes of distance. See `?dist`

```
Arguments:

       x: a numeric matrix, data frame or ‘"dist"’ object.

  method: the distance measure to be used. This must be one of
          ‘"euclidean"’, ‘"maximum"’, ‘"manhattan"’, ‘"canberra"’,
          ‘"binary"’ or ‘"minkowski"’.  Any unambiguous substring can
          be given.
```

But we can actually work around, to use it.

Date object, can be coerced into integers, if you give it an origin. By

```
x <- as.numeric(x - min(x))
```

we get number of days since the first day in record. Now we can use `dist()` with the default `Euclidean` distance:

```
y <- as.matrix(dist(x, diag = TRUE, upper = TRUE))
rownames(y) <- colnames(y) <- c("A", "B", "C")

  A B C
A 0 1 2
B 1 0 1
C 2 1 0
```

**Why putting `outer()` as my first example**

In principle, time difference is not unsigned. In this case,

```
outer(x, x, "-")
```

is more appropriate. I added the `abs()` later, because it seems that you intentionally want positive result.

Also, `outer()` has far broader use than `dist()`. Have a look at [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37914813/4891738). That OP asks for computing Hamming distance, which is really a kind of bitwise distance.

Answer (score 5):

A really fast solution using a `data.table` approach in two steps

```
# load library
 library(reshape)
 library(data.table)

# 1. Get all possible combinations of pairs of dates in long format
df <- expand.grid.df(test, test)
colnames(df) <- c("Sample", "Date", "Sample2", "Date2")

# 2. Calculate distances in days, weeks or hours, minutes etc
setDT(df)[, datedist := difftime(Date2, Date, units ="days")]

df
#>    Sample       Date Sample2      Date2 datedist
#> 1:      A 2010-10-10       A 2010-10-10   0 days
#> 2:      B 2010-10-11       A 2010-10-10  -1 days
#> 3:      C 2010-10-12       A 2010-10-10  -2 days
#> 4:      A 2010-10-10       B 2010-10-11   1 days
#> 5:      B 2010-10-11       B 2010-10-11   0 days
#> 6:      C 2010-10-12       B 2010-10-11  -1 days
#> 7:      A 2010-10-10       C 2010-10-12   2 days
#> 8:      B 2010-10-11       C 2010-10-12   1 days
#> 9:      C 2010-10-12       C 2010-10-12   0 days
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method that uses `combn` and matrix indexing.

```
# data
Sample=c("A","B", "C")
Date=as.Date(c("02/10/10", "02/10/11", "02/10/12"), format="%y/%m/%d")
# build a matrix to be filled
myMat <- matrix(0, length(Sample), length(Sample), dimnames=list(Sample, Sample))

# get all pairwise combinations (upper triangle)
samplePairs <- t(combn(Sample, 2))
# add the reverse combination (lower triangle)
samplePairs <- rbind(samplePairs, cbind(samplePairs[,2], samplePairs[,1]))
# calculate differences
diffs <- combn(Date, 2, FUN=diff)

# fill in differences using matrix indexing
myMat[samplePairs] <- diffs
```